# WSL linux and valgrind

Tags: valgrind, clion, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Whilst trying to run valgrind on WSL(windows subsystem linux) Im getting the following error: `"error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block"`

I could not find the solution anywhere.

windows OS build: 18362.

Version: 1903.

Valgrind version: 3.15-0:1 (newest)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57206233/valgrind-showing-error-calling-pr-set-ptracer-vgdb-might-block

Comment: They determined it was fixed on an older version, whilst the one who provided the answer did not notice the environment was WSL. It is not fixed. In addition, no solution was provided there either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=419562
Bug 419562 - PR_SET_PTRACER error with Ubuntu on WSL

In the bug, you see that additional information is required.